# Solving a nonhomogeneous reccurence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a nonhomoheneous recurrence to solve

$a_{n+3} - 2a_{n+2} - 5a_{n+1} + 6a_n = 2^n + n, n>=0$

I've already managed to get solution for the homogeneous part

$a_n=u1^n + v3^n + w(-2)^n$

but I can't figure out what to do with the $2^n + n$ on the right side. Could anybode give me a slight hint, please? Many thanks.

Comment: What are the initial values $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to find
particular solutions to
$a_{n+3} - 2a_{n+2} - 5a_{n+1} + 6a_n = 2^n + n, n>=0
$.

Since the coefficients
sum to zero,
let's try
$a_n = n$.
$n+3 - 2(n+2) - 5(n+1) + 6n
=3-4-5
=-6
$.

Next, $n^2$.

$\begin{array}\\
(n+3)^2 - 2(n+2)^2 - 5(n+1)^2 + 6n^2
&=n^2+6n+9- 2(n^2+4n+4) - 5(n^2+2n+1) + 6n^2\\
&=n(6-8-10)+9-8-5\\
&=-12n-4\\
\end{array}
$

Combining these,
if $a_n = un^2+vn$,
the sum is
$u(-12n-4)-6v
=-12un-4u-6v
$.
To make the $n$,
we want
$-12u = 1$
and
$-4u-6v=0$.
This gives
$u = -1/12$
and
$v = -4u/6
=(-2/3)(-1/12)
= 1/18
$.

Therefore
$a_n
=-n^2/12+n/18
$
gives $n$.

We have taken care of the "$n$" term.

Now I'll try
$a_n = 2^n$.
The sum is

$\begin{array}\\
2^{n+3} - 2\ 2^{n+2} - 5\ 2^{n+1} + 6\ 2^n
&=2^n(2^{3} - 2\ 2^{2} - 5\ 2^{1} + 6)\\
&=2^n(8 - 8 - 10 + 6)\\
&=-4\ 2^n
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $a_n
=-2^n/4
= -2^{n-2}
$,
we get $2^n$.

Therefore,
if $a_n$ is the sum of these,
or
$-2^{n-2}-n^2/12+n/18$,
this is the desired particular solution.